# Compare two dataframes to extract the new columns

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. As an example:

```
iris1<-iris[1:3]
iris2<-iris[1:4]
```

I want to extract the new column by comparing the two dataframes.
I have tried using the `compare` function from the eponymous package but no joy- it seems that comparing rows is more common. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you need `setdiff(union(names(iris1), names(iris2)), names(iris1))`

Comment: Can you not just compare the names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(union(names(iris1), names(iris2)), names(iris1))
```

Or if one of the dataset have more columns than the other while including all the columns of the second

```
setdiff(names(iris2), names(iris1))
```